# How to specify a custom formatter function gt table grand summary?

Tags: r, gt

I'm trying to use a custom formatter function to format grand summary rows in gt table.

in the example below I was trying to use seconds_to_period from lubridate but I get
the error "**Error in stop_if_not_gt(data = data) : **

```
  require(tidyverse)
  require(lubridate)

  sp500 %>%
  dplyr::filter(
    date >= "2015-01-05" &
      date <="2015-01-16"
  ) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(date) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    week = paste0(
      "W", strftime(date, format = "%V"))
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(-adj_close, -volume) %>%
  gt(
    rowname_col = "date",
    groupname_col = "week"
  ) %>%
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = vars(open, high, low, close),
    fns = list(
      min = ~min(.),
      max = ~max(.),
      avg = ~mean(.)),
    formatter = fmt(fns=seconds_to_period),
    use_seps = FALSE
  )
```

I've tried some variations like formatter = fmt(columns=vars(min),fns=seconds_to_period) with no sucess.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example

Comment: the code above is just that, copy, paste and run and you get the error message.

Comment: was this solved?

Comment: No, it's not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't share the `seconds_to_period` function, my guess is you are trying a transformation/computation with a format function. As far as I know, that's not possible. `formatter` arg allows you to apply a format to an already computed summary cell. And the sintaxys to pass the `fmt*` arguments inside `grand_summary_rows`  is quite different. Instead of passing them inside parenthesis `fmt*` function, you should pass them as `grand_summary_rows` arguments:

```r
df |>
  gt()|>
  grand_summary_rows(
      columns = vars(open, high, low, close),
      fns = list(
        min = ~min(.),
        max = ~max(.),
        avg = ~mean(.)),
      formatter = fmt_number,
      decimals = 1,
      use_seps = FALSE
)
```

In any case, in your code you're passing `use_steps`, which is a `fmt_number` argument, to a `fmt` function, which does not admit it. Take a look at [`fmt`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/fmt.html) docummentation.

Anyway, it's not clear what you a are trying to accomplish. OHLC are prices data. And I guess from your function name (`seconds_to_period`) that you're trying to give this prices data a time class format. If the case, you should compute/transform the content before trying to format it.